# How to open windows application in foreground from Java standalone application

Tags: java, windows, jna

I want to run a windows based application from java code like:

`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();`

`Process pr = rt.exec("C:\MyWindowsApplication.exe");`

This application is launched correctly but, want to know, how to make sure that, MyWindowsApplication will always open in the foreground from Java application

I tried with jna library to get the process PID number and then run VBScript with given PID number to set the windows application in the foreground.

The expected result is: if I open any windows based application from java, the application should always open in the foreground.

Comment: "I tried with jna library": and, did it work? If not, where's the code that causes the problem?

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you have written for bringing a process to foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using JNA already, you probably want to use the [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) function in the [User32 class](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.html#SetForegroundWindow-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND-).

You will need a handle to the Window to use that function.  You can use JNA's [`WindowUtils.getAllWindows()`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/WindowUtils.html#getAllWindows-boolean-) to get a list, iterate and match the title or filePath, and then call [`getHWND()`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/DesktopWindow.html#getHWND--) on the matching window.